# Next.js routing: base dynamic slug / static slug

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a situation where at the base of the url I have a dynamic slug that fetches data. Now I find I need a static slug after that which will signify a different page but still can access the base dynamic slug for information.

**Example Paths**

/formABC    (page1)

/formABC/complete   (page2)

page1 fetches data based on the dynamic slug but knows it isn't on the "complete" page

page2 fetches data based on the dynamic slug (formABC) but knows it's on the complete page

**Current Folder Structure**

```
pages/
  [formName].js
```

So 1, is this possible with next.js?

And 2 any jumping-off points I should try (file structure, predefined next methods)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's possible with the following folder structure:

```
pages/
  [formName]/
     complete.js
     index.js
```

With each pages having its own data fetching method.